# Подсказка для DataGridView. C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

Подскажите как сделать подсказку для DataGridView(ToolTip), если это возможно, чтобы при наведении курсора мыши, выводилось, к примеру, "Элементы матрицы".

Добавлял ToolTip к DataGridView и писал туда "Элементы матрицы", в надежде, что при наведении курсора появится подсказка - но нет, не появляется.

На каком-то форуме есть один вариант - для каждого столбца сделать ToolTipText - но этот вариант мне не подходит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, чтобы сделать подсказку для всей DataGridView, а не отдельных ячеек:

1. Добавляется ToolTip.
2. В св-ве DataGridView ToolTip на ToolTip1(если это первый тул тип) устанавливается текст самой подсказки.
3. Св-во DataGridView ShowCellToolTips устанавливается false.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй в **datagridview.Rows[i].Tag** загрузить информацию, после создай событие **MouseEnter** и тому подобное и через событие вызывай единый **ToolTip** и отправляй в качестве аргумента тот самый **Tag**

Comment: Спасибо за отклик, написал правильный вариант(который подошел по простоте мне) выше.